# Recreate mini fractional distillation column for oil refinery

Tags: heat-transfer, boilers

I am planning to recreate fractional distillation column in my warehouse, size not an issue however want to keep it as compact as possible (ideally should not exceed 8 meters high)

Where can I find technical diagram to start with?

I heard I need to put metal wire mesh inside column so as the gas travel up, these will capture some of the heat hence lowering down temperature?

And flowing water on top of it?

Need some ideas/suggestion where to begin. Or if any, where can find this available to purchase

Main objective is to separate into 7 separate products, from crude oil from PE plastic pyrolysis (400 C)

[image]

Thank you again for this amazing community

Comment: How will you heat the crude? Safely? How will you heat the column? What collection systems do you need? Again safely?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. It's been several attempt I made pyrolysis reactor, it produced crude oil. I am using furnace inside vacuum chamber (fueled by propane). This crude oil barely usable, but creating separate distillation will require extra heat. So, I am planning to make modification by adding fractional distillation column on top of reactor (currently all condensed gas in single container)

Comment: The crude oil you are talking about is created by pyrolysis? Pyrolysis of what? what is your existing setup, what is your actual goal? I doubt you will be able to safely achieve your goals without hiring one or more engineers.

Comment: I think @SolarMike is mostly asking because you're making a potential bomb.  The hazards here are off the charts.  How to do this is likely several Chemical Engineering classes worth of knowledge.

Comment: Yes, what Solar and Tiger said. This is a recipe for a gas explosion and oil fire at the same time, at any scale. If you are determined to do it, at least start with a very small scale device, like 100mL, and be aware that what works for that scale is probably completely insufficient in terms of safety as you go up to the next size. Get someone experienced with distillation of flammables involved in person, from the start.

Comment: @mart I guess it is something like wood tar, and I guess Lorenz doesn't really know what they're doing?

Comment: @user253751 I think you are right on both accounts.